# unable to show data entered in textarea

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views, django-templates

my views.py code:

```
 `from django.shortcuts import render
  from .forms import *
  from .models import for_point,against_point
  def index(request):
     return render(request,'debate_sample/content.html')
  def for_view(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
       form = for_form(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                  form.save()
                 all_items = for_point.objects.all
               return render(request,'debate_sample/home.html',{all_items:'all_items'})
       else:
          all_items = for_point.objects.all
          return render(request,'debate_sample/home.html',{all_items:'all_items'})
 def against_view(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
       form = against_form(request.POST or None)

           if form.is_valid():
                 form.save()
                 all_values = against_point.objects.all
                return render(request,'debate_sample/home2.html',{all_values:'all_values'})
     else:
         all_values = against_point.objects.all
         return render(request,'debate_sample/home2.html',{all_values:'all_values'})
```

`

code in home.html and similar code in home2.html

```
{% extends "debate_sample/content.html" %}

 {% block content %}
     <div class="#">
      <p>for</p>

     {% if all_items %}
          {% for things in all_items %}<br/>
             {{things.for_text}}
          {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"  method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
          <textarea name="for_text" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
          <button type="submit" name="button">submit</button>
     </form>
   </div>

   {% endblock %}
```

I am able to show the textarea and click on submit button but after clicking on submit button the text typed in textarea is not been shown below the textarea.
I have created model and model forms to write my code in views.

Comment: add `()` behind `against_point.objects.all` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're entering your context into your renders wrong. It should be `{'all_values': all_values}` You're creating a dictionary to pass into your render where the first parameter is your key and the second is your data.